# Pig latin search variabale name and min value

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig Latin question.  I have a table with the following:

```
ID:Seller:Price:BID
1:John:20:B1
1:Ben:25:B1
2:John:60:B2
2:Chris:35:B2
3:John:20:B3
```

I'm able to group the table by ID using the following (assuming `A` is the `LOAD` table):

```
W = GROUP A BY ID;
```

But what I can't seem to figure out is the command to only return the values for the lowest price for each ID.  **In this example the final output should be**:

```
1:John:20:B1
2:Chris:35:B2
3:John:20:B3
```

Cheers,
Shivedog

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how you got B1 and B2, shouldn't it B1 and B3? Do you want the lowest price by ID?

Comment: So the example I posted was a little off.  What I have are two tables:

Answer (score 0):

option (1) - get all records with maximum price:

Use the new (Pig 0.11) RANK operator:

```
A = LOAD ...;
B = RANK A BY Price DESC;
C = FILTER B BY $0=1;
```

option (2) - get all records with maximum price:

Pig version below 0.11:

```
a = load ...; 
b = group a by all; 
c = foreach b generate MAX(a.price) as maxprice; 
d = JOIN a BY price, c BY maxprice;
```

option (3) - use org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.ExtremalTupleByNthField to get one of the tuples with maximum price:

```
define mMax org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.ExtremalTupleByNthField( '4', 'max' );

a = load ...;
b = group a by all;
c - foreach b generate mMax(a);
```

Comment: Hi SNeumann, I tried that command but unfortunately we are limited to using pig 0.8.0.

Comment: Ok. So other then writing a UDF to do something similiar to RANK by executing it on a group, you could do it in pure pig by grouping and getting maximum value and then joining to the original set. i.e.:

a = load ...;
b = group a by all;
c = foreach b generate MAX(a.price) as maxprice;
d = JOIN a BY price, c BY maxprice;

Comment: @SNeumann Could you add that to your answer?  Also, it should be noted that if there are multiple items with the same minimum price this will return all of them instead of just one.

Comment: @mr2ert no problem - i'll add that. both options (RANK and GROUP+JOIN) give you all of the records with the maximum price - there's another option I'll add if you want to get just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll want to `GROUP` by the BID, then use [`MIN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#min).  However, since you want the whole tuple associated with the minimum value you'll want to use a [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#python-udfs) to do this.

**myudfs.py**

```
@outputSchema('vals: (ID: int, Seller: chararray, Price: chararray, BID: chararray)')
def get_min_tuple(bag):
    return min(bag, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

**myscript.pig**

```
register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myudfs ;

-- A: (ID: int, Seller: chararray, Price: chararray, BID: chararray)

B = GROUP A BY BID ;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group AS BID, FLATTEN(myudfs.get_min_tuple(A)) ;

-- Now you can do the JOIN to get the type of novel on C
```

Remember change the types (int,chararray,etc.) to the appropriate values.

**Note:** If multiple items in `A` have the same minimum price for an ID, then this will only return one of them.